# Populate sql statement based on several checkboxes on JSF and Java

Tags: java, arrays, jsf, checkbox, javabeans

I have a jsf page which contains multiple checkboxes populated with values from the database.  From these checkboxes, I have to build an sql statement according to the checkboxes the user clicked on.

I have a button which passes the values of the checkboxes to my backing bean.

What I want to know is how can I get the value of each checkbox the user clicked on and build my sql statement?

For example, in my Java class I have this variable

```
private String mysql = "select * from table_name ";
private String param;
//setter getter for param
```

Lets say param value will be: `checkbox1=1&checkbox2=jane&checkbox3=25`

```
if (!param.isEmpty())
{
// populate sql statement here
}
```

Sql statement should be:

```
select * from table_name where column1=1 and column2='jane' and column3=25
```

How to use a for each loop to get each value of the checkbox and for each checkbox value which is present, I concatenate with my sql statement?

Comment: It look like that you're not using JSF components at all to represent checkboxes and bind the checked values. Giving a suitable answer as to getting the checkbox values is therefore hard. Building the SQL statement is a completely different question. JSF is irrelevant in this question. You just start off with a `List<String>` or something. You're basically asking 2 questions in 1 question. I'd suggest to reframe your question.

Comment: @BalusC The checkboxes are created using the List itself in the xhtml page through a dataTable.  There are numerous checkboxes and according to the number of checkboxes i clicked upon, i want to build the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how a for loop comes into the equation, you say you are getting your checkbox values in distinct parameters, which is good. So now, you just need to construct your SQL string. Note that it is an ***extremely*** bad idea to create SQL queries by concatenating user supplied strings. This opens you wide up for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Do something like this instead:

```
final String value1 = "value from checkbox1";
final String value2 = "value from checkbox2";
final String value3 = "value from checkbox3";

final Connection conn = ... ; // Get your connection
final PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from table_name where column1=? and column2=? and column3=?");
preparedStmt.setObject(1, value1);
preparedStmt.setObject(2, value2);
preparedStmt.setObject(3, value3);
final ResultSet results = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: quite nice but there will be other checkboxes in my page and i only want the values of the checkboxes checked.  That is why only one value is being defined in the java class and i am trying to get the value of every checkbox checked and add them to my sql statement.

Comment: this is only for 3 checkboxes.. i have about 15 checkboxes of different categories in my page, thats why i am asking about a for loop to get the values of the checkboxes in java

Comment: Are you mirroring your db in the form of checkboxes on a web page?

Comment: yes you can say that. Have these checkboxes act as filters, so whenever a user checks several checkboxes randomly a SQL statement is built and the result is returned